# Roku RAF is throwing Error when playing the video continuously

Tags: roku

The ad playback with HLS stream is working fine if I play the content one by one with some time gap between each playback.

But, If I play the video without any time gap, for certain playbacks the ad is not showing and the RAF is throwing some error as ***No Ads VAST Response***

The pod URL I'm using is `https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vmap&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ar%3Dpremidpostoptimizedpod&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator=`

Any one know why this happening?!
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically an error - seems the case is just that the ad server did not return any ads on ad request, which is rather common occurrence.

Specifically for GAM, i seem to remember for returning empty response on "duplicate" requests. And/or it could be frequency-capping, it runs out of ads for particular device (individual ad campaigns have limits placed on them, things like "don't show same ad more often than once per hour, totally 3x per day")

Comment: This happens only when I hide the player and unhide the player immediately.
When hiding the player I'm actually removing the RAF object and then on unhiding I'm creating a new RAF object.

Comment: When I remove the old RAF object and create a new one without hiding the player, I'm getting the Ad response correctly